# Mylyn and Bugzilla : Initialization of task failed?

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla, mylyn

I'm trying to connect Mylyn (eclipse Juno) to my bugzilla installation (version 3.6.3.0-2)...
I was able to add bugzilla as a task repo, but I can't add any task.
As soon as I click on New Task for this repo, I get this message (the task editor does not even appear):

Initialization of task failed. The provided data is insufficient.

I was unable to find anything in the Eclipse Error Log.

Any idea what went wrong ? (Googling was no help)

**EDIT** :

- I've validated my credentials on finish for the repo
- I've created a
  default query.

thanks in advance.

Comment: did you create at least one task query filter?

Comment: I've never seen this error (and I've seen a lot of Mylyn errors over the years).  I assume you 'validated' your credentials when you created the task repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same issue and came across this post.
I created a query as guido suggested [right clicked on the repo in the Task Repositories > New Query] and was able to to create new tasks through the Task List area. Right clicking on the repo itself in the Task Repositories section still yields that error.

So go into the Task List and create your tasks there [click the button for New Task]